# ошибка при работе с SceneBuilder в Eclipse

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse

При запуске программы вылетает такая ошибка и ничего не запускается:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:javafx.graphics@10.0.2/javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.graphics@10.0.2/javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
>   at application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
>
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

изменил в классе `Main.java` в методе `start` объект `BorderPane` на `AnchorPane`, потому что сделал такое же изменение в SceneBuilder